# SQL Query Error: Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I have this problem, I can't seem to search on google.
This is my school work so please be patient with my coding.
Now the problem is i am doing a select query and SQL does not seem to recognize the column I need

here is an attached picture, it just says invalid column but it is clear that the column exist

[Dropbox link to the picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xuaxt2ppfzub12/Capture6.JPG?dl=0)

here is the complete code

```
create database Hairsalon

use Hairsalon   

create table Employee
(
    Employee_ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(20),
    Birthday date,
    Gender char(1)
);

create table Inventory
(
    Inventory_ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(30),
    Stock int   
)

create table Record
(
    Transaction_Number int primary key,
    Transaction_Date date,
    Transaction_Time time
);

alter table Record
    drop column Transaction_Date
alter table Record
    drop column Transaction_Time
alter table Record
    add Transaction_DT varchar(30)
alter table Record
    add Transaction_Description varchar(255)

Create table Inventory_Record
(
    Transaction_Number int primary key foreign key references Record(Transaction_Number),
    Inventory_ID int foreign key references Inventory(Inventory_ID),
);

create table Customer_Record
(
    Transaction_Number int foreign key references Record(Transaction_Number),
    Customer_ID int primary key,
    Service_Description varchar(255),
    Pay money
);

create table Customer
(
    Customer_ID int foreign key references Customer_Record(Customer_ID),
    Name varchar(20),
    Payable money,
    Session_DT varchar(20)
);

create table Employee_Record
(
    Transaction_Number int primary key foreign key references Record(Transaction_Number),
    Employee_ID int foreign key references Employee(Employee_ID),
    Time_In time,
    Time_Out time,
    Record_Date date,
    Customer_Count int
);

create table Salon
(
    Customer_ID  int foreign key references Customer_Record(Customer_ID),
    Employee_ID  int foreign key references Employee(Employee_ID),
    Inventory_ID int foreign key references Inventory(Inventory_ID),
    Transaction_Number int foreign key references Record(Transaction_Number)
);

alter table Customer
    add Session_DT varchar(20)

alter table Customer
    drop column Customer_ID
alter table Customer
    add Customer_ID int foreign key references Customer_Record(Customer_ID)

alter table Customer_Record
    add Employee_ID int foreign key references Employee(Employee_ID)

alter table Employee
    add [Type] varchar(15)

alter table Employee
    drop column Birthday
    alter table Employee
    drop column Birthday

alter table Employee_Record
    drop column Time_In
alter table Employee_Record
    drop column Time_Out
alter table Employee_Record
    drop column Record_Date
alter table Employee_Record
    add Time_In varchar(20)
alter table Employee_Record
    add Time_Out varchar(20)
alter table Employee_Record
    add Record_Date varchar(20)
alter table Employee_Record
    drop column Customer_Count

insert into Employee 
values(1,'Test Employee','M','Cashier','bday')
insert into Employee 
values(-1,'Null','N','Null','Null')
insert into Employee values(1,'test1','M','HairDresser','9/8/2014')

INSERT INTO Record  values(2,'')
INSERT INTO Customer_Record values(1,1,'asd',123.00,null)
INSERT INTO Customer values(1,'test1',0,'9/8/2014 8:16 AM')

SELECT * FROM Record
select * from Customer
SELECT * FROM Customer_Record
SELECT * FROM Employee

SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Name as 'Customer Name', Employee.Name as 'Attendee'
FROM Customer, Customer_Record, Employee_Record, Employee
WHERE ( Customer_Record.Transaction_Number = Employee_Record.Transaction_Number 
        AND Employee_Record.Employee_ID = Employee.Employee_ID
        AND Customer.Customer_ID = Customer_Record.Customer_ID
        ) OR ( Customer_Record.Transaction_Number = Employee_Record.Transaction_Number 
        AND Customer_Record.Employee_ID = -1
        AND Customer.Customer_ID = Customer_Record.Customer_ID
        )

insert into Employee_Record values(9,1,'10:00','10:99','date')

select * from Record
select * from Customer
select * from Employee
select * from Employee_Record
select * from Customer_Record

select count(Customer_ID) from Customer
select count(Transaction_Number) from Record

insert into Customer
values(1,'test',120,DATEFROMPARTS(32,12,31))

INSERT INTO Customer_Record values(1,1,'Long Haired Customer: ',0, null)

DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = 1

DELETE FROM Customer
DELETE FROM Customer_Record
DELETE FROM Record

DELETE FROM Employee
DELETE FROM Employee_Record
DELETE FROM Inventory
DELETE FROM Inventory_Record

commit
```

Comment: Do you actually receive an error when you run the statement? From the attached image it looks like Intellisense doesn't recognise the column but it should run.

Comment: it runs, with no error,
it has the squigly red lines though that says invalid column when I hover

Comment: As @Ndech says below, this is probably an Intellisense cache problem, use Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh the cache.
Alternatively put the statement ```GO``` in your query after you have created your tables and altered them and before your select statements. ```GO``` is used by SSMS to break the query up into batches it understands.

Comment: I would recommend that you ditch the old style JOINS and start using the SQL92 standard INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.col1 = tableB.col2. See https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the DDL you have presented, it seems quite obvious that Customer_Record has no Employee_ID.

You may have mixed up Customer_Record with Employee_Record or Employee_ID with Customer_ID, but something is wrong.

**EDIT** I had missed that you alter the table in your script to add the missing columns. In that case, Intellisense (the auto-completion system) does not take it into account unless you manually reload it (using Ctrl + Shift + R). Your query is correct and the errors will disappear once Intellisense is up to date.

Comment: To add to this answer it's likely the Object Explorer in SSMS is simply out of sync. Try refreshing the table (right-click, refresh; or hit the refresh button at the top). That, or it's showing a different database/server where you had a different schema.

Comment: And furthermore `= null` will always be false. You must mean `is null`. See also [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-...ls-null/](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-sql-server-mistakes-\_1320\_-equals-null/)

Comment: well i kind of have this query
    alter table Customer_Record
    add Employee_ID int foreign key references Employee(Employee_ID)

and on the object explorer it shows that there is a foreign key to Employee_ID

i'm on my dead end

Comment: Ok I had missed that. As suggested by @lc, it is probably an intellisence problem. Try hitting Ctrl + Shift + R to reload it.