# My SQL query is returned with error saying invalid column name whereas column exists and it works in Oracle SQL dev IDE

Tags: sql, oracle

The same query is giving correct results in Oracle SQL Developer whereas in Java, it throws an error.

```
SELECT 
    LOGIN_ID AS GROUPID, FILENAME,
    TO_CHAR (CREATEDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AS CREATDATE,
    CASE STATUS 
        WHEN 2300 THEN 'File downloaded and deleted'
        WHEN 2200 THEN 'File Downloaded but not deleted'
        WHEN 2100 THEN 'File Created' END STATUS,UMI,PAYLOAD 
FROM 
    CC_CCS_SRD_ADM.TB_MAILBOX_OUTBOUND 
WHERE 
    LOGIN_ID = 'HCLLIN02' 
ORDER BY 
    CREATDATE DESC
```

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)

The results are fetched fine as below in SQL developer:

[image]

I tried to run this query in query as mentioned in
[SQL Query Error: Invalid Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719505/sql-query-error-invalid-column-name) and it went as - Login_ID Invalid identifier .

My modified query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         LOGIN_ID AS GROUPID, FILENAME,
         TO_CHAR (CREATEDDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AS CREATDATE,
         CASE STATUS 
             WHEN 2300 THEN 'File downloaded and deleted'
             WHEN 2200 THEN 'File Downloaded but not deleted'
             WHEN 2100 THEN 'File Created' 
         END STATUS, UMI, PAYLOAD 
     FROM 
         CC_CCS_SRD_ADM.TB_MAILBOX_OUTBOUND) DT 
WHERE 
    LOGIN_ID = 'HCLLIN02' 
ORDER BY 
    CREATDATE DESC;
```

Ok and Here in this edit , adding my java lines:

```
query = "   SELECT LOGIN_ID as GROUPID, \n" +
                    "        FILENAME,TO_CHAR (CREATEDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AS CREATDATE,\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\t\tDECODE (STATUS,2300,'File downloaded and deleted',2200,'File Downloaded but not deleted', 2100,'File Created' ) STATUS,UMI,PAYLOAD \n" +
                    "\t\t\t\t\tFROM CC_CCS_SRD_ADM.TB_MAILBOX_OUTBOUND\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\t\tWHERE LOGIN_ID = 'HCLLIN02' ORDER BY createddate DESC";
                    stringBuilder.append(query);
            logger.info("after Append Query ");
        }

        try
        {
            logger.info("inside try block..");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(stringBuilder.toString());
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //logger.info("inside select success block.."+ rs.getString(groupId));
                TreeMap<String, String> mapToAdd = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                mapToAdd.put("GroupID",rs.getString("GROUPID"));
                mapToAdd.put("FileName",rs.getString("FILENAME"));
                mapToAdd.put("umi", rs.getString("UMI"));
                mapToAdd.put("status", rs.getString("STATUS"));
                //mapToAdd.put("PAYLOAD", rs.getString("PAYLOAD"));
                mapToAdd.put("CreateDate", rs.getString("CREATEDATE"));
```

Comment: 1) what is the DDL for the table?  2) if you removed LOGIN_ID from the query does it run (even if you just select a count from the table) 3) Are you sure you're connecting to the same databzse the SQL developer query hits and in same schema?

Comment: You put your original query in a subquery where "login_id" is now "groupid"...

Comment: yes I am using the same creds as in sql developer - its an admin login. is it supposed to be logged in only 1 instance at a time ? @xQbert

Comment: It might be helpful to include your Java code as that is what's causing the error. Your SQL isn't erroring; your attempt to get a value form the result set is. I'd guess you're asking for `"LOGIN_NAME"` but as already pointed out you alias that so you need to ask for `"GROUPID"`. Or possibly it's case sensitive, or you just have a typo.

Comment: it says invalid column name - any ways i tried by giving as GroupID still same error - query = "SELECT \n" +
     "LOGIN_ID as GROUPID,\n" +
     "FILENAME,TO_CHAR (CREATEDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AS CREATDATE,\n" +
     "DECODE(STATUS,2300,'File downloaded and deleted',2200,'File Downloaded but not deleted', 2100,'File Created'\n" +
     ") STATUS,\n" +
     "UMI,PAYLOAD \n" +
     "FROM CC_CCS_SRD_ADM.TB_MAILBOX_OUTBOUND " +

     "   WHERE GROUPID = 'HCLLIN02' ORDER BY createddate DESC\n";  Error : ORA-00904: GROUPID: Invalid Identifier

Comment: No, you're confusing several things. p3consulting's comment was about the modified query at the end of your question. You have changed the original query, and you can't refer to `GROUPID` in the `WHERE` clause. Go back to the original query, and change how you retrieve the column value *in Java*. The original query was OK (ish), the issue seems to be that you're doing something like `rSet.getString("LOGIN_ID")` instead of `rSet.GetString("GROUPID")`. If you included your Java code in your question we'd have a clear idea of exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: yes you are right, I was getting column names which are not in the result set. Thanks much for this point

Comment: Don't think you need the \n \t in the string.  Not sure how the SQL parser will process those.  SUre it makes it easier to read in the  println; but it might be what's causing issue with the SQL.

Comment: Change `WHERE LOGIN_ID = 'HCLLIN02'` to `WHERE GROUPID = 'HCLLIN02'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rename your column name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         LOGIN_ID AS GROUPID, FILENAME,
         TO_CHAR (CREATEDDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AS CREATDATE,
         CASE STATUS 
             WHEN 2300 THEN 'File downloaded and deleted'
             WHEN 2200 THEN 'File Downloaded but not deleted'
             WHEN 2100 THEN 'File Created' 
         END STATUS, UMI, PAYLOAD 
     FROM 
         CC_CCS_SRD_ADM.TB_MAILBOX_OUTBOUND) DT 
WHERE 
    GROUPID = 'HCLLIN02' 
ORDER BY 
    CREATDATE DESC;
```

Comment: A guess: GROUPID LOGIN)ID, FILENAME may be a reserved word in the database server.  Oracle database server noted.

Comment: thanks - it is working - the issue is i was trying to find column name which is not part of result set